# Python: automating the generation of a variable number of if statements

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, if-statement, inequalities

I have two numpy arrays similar to these, which represent coordinates:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array([1,3,2,4,6,5,4,1])
y=np.array([4,4,3,2,2,1,3,5])
```

I also have `n` squares:

```
s1 -> x=0 to 3, y=0 to 3
s2 -> x=3 to 6, y=3 to 6
s3 -> ...
s4 -> ...
```

and I want to count the number of points falling within each square. This comes down to evaluating `n` inequalities.

My approach is verbose and (probably) inefficient:

```
count1=0
count2=0
count3=0
count4=0
for j in range(0, len(x)):
    #Square 1
    if x[j]<=3 and y[j]<=3:
        count1+=1
    #Square 2
    if x[j]<=3 and y[j]>3 and y[j]<=6:
        count2+=1
    #Square 3
    if x[j]>3 and x[j]<=6 and y[j]<=3:
        count3+=1
    #Square 4
    if x[j]>3 and x[j]<=6 and y[j]>3 and y[j]<=6:
        count4+=1
```

Given my two arrays, this returns:

```
In[1]: count1, count2, count3, count4
Out[1]: (1, 3, 4, 0)
```

My real problems consists of a variable number of squares (it could be 6, it could be 36, etc.).

Is there a way I can automate both the generation of the `count` variables, as well as the number and boundaries of the `if` statements?

Comment: couldn't you put the boundaries of the squares in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't list your whole code, so, it's not clear what exactly you are trying to do. In any case, you could describe each square by a tuple of tuples

```
square_n = ((x1, x2), (y1, y2))
```

and put them in a dictionary, where the key this tuple, and the value is the count. Then, something like

```
for square in squares_dict:
    (x1, x2), (y1, y2) = square
    if x1<a<x2 and y1<b<y2: # whatever criterion you have
        squares_dict[square] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where an array is very useful.

Rather than making individual `countn` variables, you can make a count array, and index into that array (so `count0` becomes `count[0]`, `count1` to `count[1]`, and so on).

Now the trick is just mapping the x and y coordinates to a particular count array index, which you can do with just some math. i.e., if the squares are 3x3 and arranged in a large rectangle, then `x // 3 + (y // 3) * num_squares_per_row` gives you your index.

In the case that your regions that you're trying to count aren't uniform, so you can't come up with an easy math equation, you can always make a dictionary mapping the things you want to count to their indices in the `count` array, and use that to figure out what index to increment given a particular input.